# How to make shadow and border styles be applied to both div(inside input) and input as one single element?

Tags: html, css

I need to insert div element in the right corner of input text field (it's a search field), but styles are applied only to search field, like div element is inserted not inside of it and is not part of it

```
     <form class="search_form">

                     <input type="text" value="Введіть назву події" >


                   <div type='button' class="city_select">
                   </div> 
                         </input>

</form>
```

How to do so that shadows and borders are applied to both div and input as one single element?

Comment: A div cannot be inserted in an input text field. An input text field can be inserted into a div

Comment: @repzero so the only way is to make it look like single?

Comment: there are a couple of tricks and work around like applying the same css style from the input box to the div so it looks the same..hmmm...how would you like your expected results to look?are you putting a search icon in that div or something else?

Comment: @repzero select city thing, so it there is a location sign and div with city name . the main thing is that shadows and border must be applied to all of them, like it's a single elements. background is the same, same shadow and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing a closing div and you shouldn't need to put the div inside the input element.

Put the button div after the input element and have both inside the make_elegant_form div. Set position: relative on both the parent make_elegant_form div and the button div. Then you use a negative number to position the button div left. Something like this (from the top of my head):

HTML:

```
<form class="search_form">
    <div class="make_elegant_form">
        <input type="text" value="Введіть назву події" ></input>
        <div type='button' class="city_select"></div
    </div> 
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.make_elegant_form {
    position: relative;
}

.city_select {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
}
```

UPDATE: I see you have edited the code in your question. If all you want is to have a border and shadow on the whole form, you just apply them to the parent div. In this case the .make_elegant_form div (the one you removed). You can not style the form element.

The input element may have a border as default style, but you can remove this with:

```
.search_form input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: tried to apply on the parent div. both shadow and border and strangely twice bigger at top then element's height

Comment: that could be several things. take a look at this pen: codepen.io/anon/pen/wJpNyw

Comment: you would probably also need to set a max-width on the input so it doesn't overflow the city selector.

Comment: please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42889898/styles-are-not-applied-to-both-input-text-form-and-div-and-search-button